# Active Record has_many relationship three levels deep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :zipcodes
  belongs_to :state
end

class Zipcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end
```

When I try doing:

```
State.first.cities.zipcodes
```

I get an `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` error.

Does anyone know how to go multiple levels deep using the has_many relationship?  I did get this working using the `through:` option, but is there anyway to do it without using the `through:` option?

Answer (score 5):

### What you need is

Add another association clause to you city class like this

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
  has_many :zipcodes, through: :cities 
end
```

then you can just call

```
state.zipcodes
```

which will return all zipcodes for a given state (via associated cities)

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
State.first.cities.first.zipcodes
```

This is because `State.first.cities` returns a collection since its a has_many relationship between state and city

Comment: But what if I wanted to search for all zipcodes in a specified state?

Answer (score 0):

Without using `:through`, you would need to iterate over each City and find its zipcodes:

```
State.first.cities.map(&:zipcodes)
```

Comment: Hmm ok, so I guess it's better to just use through:, since the database will be doing the work as opposed to ruby.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `:through`? This is an appropriate use of it.

Comment: I have a lot of tables in my database (60+) and I wanted to avoid writing all the :through relationships.